# ASP .NET's Automatically Logged Errors

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net

ASP .NET logs lots of warnings out-of-the-box. Does anyone know what will make ASP .NET log an **error** into the Windows Application event log?

I'm wondering if I can have a program that runs once a day or so to search for errors to make sure the server hasn't spontaneously blown up or fallen off the Internet for a moment. (think along the lines of those classic stories of "and the server mysteriously rebooted every 15 minutes at 4:09 AM").

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not to the Windows Event Logs - this is much better....

You can try [ELMAH](http://www.raboof.com/projects/Elmah/)  see this handy article from Scott Hanselman

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Comment: I'm using ELMAH. I'm concerned about the crashes that will fall through, such as if the web.config or the permissions get messed up.